# Jquery ui drag and drop form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I'm doing a screen where the user can drag an item and drop in a droppable field. I'm using the jquery ui.

This draggable item is a div with an input hidden.
The droppable field is a form.

I need that the user select the items drop in the field and submit it to a php code.

But, i'm having three problems.

1- I need to show the hidden input when the item be dropped on the field, but all itens are being visible and not the selected one.

2- I cannot put the item back to the draggable list when its dropped in the field.

3- I cannot write in the hidden camp when the draggable iten its dropped in the field.

The question is that i just need to select draggable div and drop in a field to submit to a form. I think it's very easy, but i'm having trouble with it.

Please, could you give me some help?

Thanks.

I have no experience with jquery ui.

```
$( function() {

    $( ".drag" ).draggable({

        containment: "document", 
        helper: "clone",
        cursor: "move"

    });
    $( "#drop" ).droppable({
        classes: {
        "ui-droppable-active": "custom-state-active"
      },
        drop: function (event, ui){
            $('.inputAtributo').css('display','block');
            adicionaAtributo(ui.draggable);
        },
        out: function (event, ui) {
        $(ui.draggable).fadeOut(1000, function () {
            $(this).remove();
            $(this).appendTo(".campo-inicial");
            $('.inputAtributo').css('display','none');
            $(this).fadeIn();
            $( ".drag" ).draggable({     
                containment: "document", 
                helper: "clone",
                cursor: "move"  
            });
        });
    }
    });

function adicionaAtributo($atributo){
    $atributo.appendTo('form');     
}

    });
```

I need to submit draggable divs to a form.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question and title are a little confusing. Please clarify what you are trying to accomplish or what is not working.

Comment: Also, `$(this).remove();` might not have the intended result. Also once removed, it cannot be appended to another item. You may want to research `.detach()`.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example I would also suggest the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour